# Export Excel Data to Json dynamic Array with VBA

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, dynamic

I have some data in excel that I am looping through with VBA in order to create a nested JSON string.

ColumnF contains values a, b and c, in row 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

[image: Excel Tabel here]

I am using the following code:

```
Public Sub Excel_to_json()

Dim mainContainer As New Dictionary, rulesArray As New Collection, rulesContainer As New Dictionary

Dim excelRange As Range

Set excelRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

    mainContainer("ColumnA") = Cells(1, 1)
    mainContainer("ColumnB") = Cells(1, 2)
    mainContainer("ColumnC") = Cells(1, 3)
    mainContainer("ColumnD") = Cells(1, 4)

    rulesContainer("ColumnE") = Cells(1, 5)
    rulesContainer("ColumnF") = Array(Cells(1, 6), Cells(2, 6), Cells(3, 6))

    rulesContainer("ColumnG") = Cells(1, 7)

    rulesContainer("ColumnH") = Cells(1, 8)
    rulesContainer("ColumnI") = Cells(1, 9)
    rulesContainer("ColumnJ") = Cells(1, 10)
    rulesContainer("ColumnK") = Cells(1, 11)
    rulesContainer("ColumnL") = Cells(1, 12)
    rulesContainer("ColumnM") = Cells(1, 13)
    rulesContainer("ColumnN") = Cells(1, 14)

    rulesArray.Add rulesContainer

    mainContainer.Add "rules", rulesArray

    Debug.Print ConvertToJson(mainContainer, Whitespace:=2)

End Sub
```

I get the results I want, namely:

```
{
  "ColumnA": 1,
  "ColumnB": 2,
  "ColumnC": 3,
  "ColumnD": 4,
  "rules": [
    {
      "ColumnE": 5,
      "ColumnF": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ],
      "ColumnG": 7,
      "ColumnH": 8,
      "ColumnI": 9,
      "ColumnJ": 10,
      "ColumnK": 11,
      "ColumnL": 12,
      "ColumnM": 13,
      "ColumnN": 14
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is rather how I replace the following piece of code:

`rulesContainer("ColumnF") = Array(Cells(1, 6), Cells(2, 6), Cells(3, 6))` in order to load a dynamic array which could have a different number of objects inside? In order words, since I might have a variable number of objects inside the array (not just [ "a", "b", "c" ]), is it possible to load the array so that it becomes dynamic [ "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?" ]? How can we load such array using VBA? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `Array(Cells(1, 6), Cells(2, 6), Cells(3, 6))` translates to be just `range("f1:f3").value` so you could look at using `resize` based on the data, so `rulesContainer("ColumnF")=range("f1:f" & lngRows).value` may be an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()` to convert the range values from 2 dimensional array that has only 1 column to 1 dimensional array.

> ```
>  rulesContainer("ColumnF") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("F1", Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)).Value)
> ```

[image: Immediate Window]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very efficient solution.